# VBA: How to retrieve ListObject-Column-Count of given element in HeaderRowRange?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, header-row

I am trying (and failing) to find a given string in the HeaderRowRange of a ListObject. I would like to pull the ListObject-Column Count (not the spreadsheet-column count). I am trying to address with using ".index", however, it is running into an error. What is wrong with the below code?

See screenshot to understand better my goal:
w/in the ListObject Column3 is the 3rd column, while w/in the worksheet it is column 6 (column F). I want the j in my code to be 3 (not 6).

[image]

```
Sub MWE()
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("worksheet1")
Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("table1")
Dim j As Long: j = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find("Column3", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Index
End Sub
```

Comment: What about `lo.ListColumns("Column3").Index`

Answer (score 2):

As I know the name of the column header, I can simply use this code to get the column count w/in the ListObject:

```
j= lo.ListColumns("Column3").Index
```

Answer (score 1):

`.Find` returns a range object. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("worksheet1")
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set aCell = lo.HeaderRowRange.Find("Column3", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox aCell.Column
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can also use `Application.Match`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("worksheet1")
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim j As Long: j = Application.Match("Column3", lo.HeaderRowRange, 0)
    
    MsgBox j
End Sub
```

**PS**: You also have a typo in your code. `Dim lo As listoject` should be `Dim lo As ListObject`

**EDIT**

> See screenshot to understand better my goal: w/in the ListObject Column3 is the 3rd column, while w/in the worksheet it is column 6 (column F). I want the j in my code to be 3 (not 6).

In such a case if your table doesn't start from Col `A` then you will have to do the range adjustment. Change `MsgBox aCell.Column` to `MsgBox aCell.Column - lo.HeaderRowRange.Column + 1` in the first code.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: The application.match works perfectly. Still thinking about the .find-approach: If I understand your comment correctly, it is basically not possible to pull something w/in a ListOject as .find refers to ranges which again make reference to the whole worksheet.

Comment: @user3601876  I would suggest to use `Dim j As Variant`. Only for the case when "Column3" does not match anything in the searched range. Then use `If Not IsError(j) Then MsgBox j`. In the suggested way, it will not rise an error, even without checking using `IsError` it will return "Error 2042", if the string could not be found...

Comment: Voted it up.  I think that the above suggestion can make the `Match` part more versatile...

Comment: *".. I want the `j` in my code to be 3 (not 6)"* - As the `.Find` results itself in a *range object* within the given worksheet and its `.Column` property returns the column therein (e.g. 6), you can calculate the wanted column position within the listobject by a subtraction as follows:  `6` *minus* the listobject 's start column (`- lo.Range.Cells(1, 1).Column`) plus `+1` (as there is no zero column) :-) @user3601876

Comment: In addition to @FaneDuru 's valid comment: As the late bound `Application.Match` is expected to return a position number in case something is found, it's also possible to exclude *non-findings* via the following condition: `If IsNumeric(j) Then MsgBox j` instead of negating an error :-)

Comment: @user3601876 if your table doesn't start from Col A then you will have to do the range adjustment. Change `MsgBox aCell.Column` to `MsgBox aCell.Column - lo.HeaderRowRange.Column + 1`

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to access the column in `listobject table` other than `hearderRow`, hope you find it useful

```
Sub tt()

Dim tb1 As ListObject
Dim rcol As Range

Set tb1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
Set rcol = tb1.ListColumns("Ctry").DataBodyRange

Debug.Print rcol(3).Value  'Hawaii

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthRout, i come out with other method to find the headerRow also lol